# Transparent Image not working in Shape Script

Tags: enterprise-architect

Trying to add an image to the shape script while defining MDG technology profile.Transparent images which i add becomes opaque when adding inside MDG like below ( Tranparent is replaced with black background)

[image]

Is there any work around for it ..? Am adding .PNG image

Any work around for it.?

Comment: What is your EA version?

Comment: @ThomasKilian 12.1.1224

Comment: Transparency has been added in V11 IIRC. Seems this has not been tested with shape script. Report a bug. EMF/WMF should work, though.

Comment: I think I've seen some release notes recently mentioning better handling of transparency. Might be worth to upgrade and see if it is still a problem. But in this case I would replace your image by a regular shapescript. Seems simple enough.